# the value of an exercise with matrices

Tags: matrices

I have the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & -1\\ 
1 &1 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $A^{n}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_{n} & -y_{n}\\ 
y_{n} &x_{n} 
\end{pmatrix}$

At first exercise I found that $2A-A^{2}=2I_{2}$.At the second exercise I found that $A^{48}=2^{24}I_{2}$.

I got stuck at the last exercise where I need find the value of $$\frac{x_{10}^{2}+y_{10}^2}{x_{8}^{2}+y_{8}^2}=?$$

I tried to multiplicate these 2 matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
x_{10} & -y_{10}\\ 
y_{10} &x_{10} 
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}
x_{10} & -y_{10}\\ 
y_{10} &x_{10} 
\end{pmatrix}$ but I don't get something useful.How to approach this exercise?

Comment: I have to admit, I clicked on this question hoping to find a philosophical enquiry into the merits of doing matrix exercises

Comment: My bad, I didn't choose a very  good title of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^2 = 2\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $A^4 = -4 I$,
$A^8 = 16 I$.
Hence $(x_8,y_8) = (16,0)$, $(x_{10}, y_{10}) = (0,32)$.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Let $z\in\mathbb C$ and $z = x+iy$ with $x,y\in\mathbb R$. Put $A_z := \begin{pmatrix}x&-y\\y&x\end{pmatrix}$. Then, if $z,w\in\mathbb C$ you have $A_{z+w} = A_z+A_w$ and (more important) $A_{zw} = A_zA_w$. Your matrix is $A_{1+i}$, hence $x_n+iy_n = (1+i)^n$ and thus
$$
x_n^2+y_n^2 = |x_n+iy_n|^2 = |(1+i)^n|^2 = |1+i|^{2n} = \sqrt{2}^{2n} = 2^n.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{x_{10}^2+y_{10}^2}{x_{8}^2+y_{8}^2} = \frac{2^{10}}{2^8} = 2^2 = 4.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help!